# Android MaterialDialog Spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner, material-design, android-dialog

I'm using MaterialDialog.Builder to show a dialog.
I set a customView for my dialog.

In my layout i have a spinner and i want to populate it form my sqlite database when i show the dialog.

The callback function only works when i push those buttons. Is there a function that i can use before dialog shows and use the layout that i set to append the spinner ?

My code is like :

```
boolean wrapInScrollView = true;
new MaterialDialog.Builder(mContext)
.customView(layout, wrapInScrollView)
.autoDismiss(false)
.negativeText(R.string.text40)
.positiveText(buton)
.callback(new MaterialDialog.ButtonCallback() { ....})
.build()
.show();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that you have `LinearLayout` and inside you have `Spinner`:

- custom `xml` file name is `"dialogCustom"`
- `linearlayout` id inside it is `"linearLayoutMine"`
- `spinner` id inside `linearlayout` is `"mySpinner"`

  ```
  MaterialDialog.Builder md=new MaterialDialog.Builder(this);

  LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
  final View stdView = factory.inflate(R.layout.dialogCustom, null);
  LinearLayout linearLayoutMine (LinearLayout) stdView.findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutMine);
  Spinner spinner = (Spinner) linearLayoutMine.findViewById(R.id.mySpinner);

  //Load items to spinner

  md.title("myTitle")
    .customView(linearLayoutMine, wrapInScrollView)
    .autoDismiss(false)
    .negativeText(R.string.text40)
    .positiveText(buton)
    .callback(new MaterialDialog.ButtonCallback() { ....})
    .build()
    .show();
  ```

Callbacks are only for when positive, negative buttons are pressed.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to separate build() and show() calls and use getCustomView() after build().

Like this

```
dlg = new MaterialDialog.Builder(mContext)
    .customView(layout, wrapInScrollView)
    .autoDismiss(false)
    .negativeText(R.string.text40)
    .positiveText(buton)
    .callback(new MaterialDialog.ButtonCallback() { ....})
    .build();


mySpinner = (Spinner)dlg.getCustomView.findViewById(R.id.mySpinner);
// do whatever you need to do with your spinner

// finally show the dialog
dlg.show();
```

This is not necessarily better than the approach suggested by Jemshit, just a different way to achieve the result.