# use material dialog in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, material-design

I'm using `material-dialogs library`
https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs 
my problem is I can't use the lib in the fragment

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        layout=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_option, null);
        new MaterialDialog.Builder(this) //the problem is this line
           .title("test")
           .content("test")
           .show();
        return layout;
    }
```

I have tried below methods but they failed

```
 new MaterialDialog.Builder(getActivity())
 new MaterialDialog.Builder(this.getActivity())
 new MaterialDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this) //MainActivity is the parent activity
```

Thank you for any help you can provide

Comment: Have you tried `getSupportActivity()` ?

Comment: I think not ! Could you explain more detail? what's that?

Comment: [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29577607/android-materialdialog-spinner) may helps you

Comment: There is on `getSupportActivity()` in class `Fragment`, see my answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get `context` in `onCreateView()` method of `Fragment` because fragment in not added to `Activity`.

The only way is to get `Context` in `onAttach(Activity activity)` (or later methods of `Fragment`s lifecicle) method of `Fragment`.

So you could show dialog this way:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
super.onAttach(activity);
Context ctx=this.getActivity();
new MaterialDialog.Builder(ctx)
       .title("test")
       .content("test")
       .show();
}
```

**UPD_0:**

Make sure you're using version 23.0.1 of Google libs (AppCompat, Support Library, etc.) in your own app. ([link](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs/issues/701))

**UPD_1:**

Since `onAttach(Activity activity)` is deprecated, use `onAttach(Context context)`

Comment: @Johnny What kind of error you get it logCat? Also try code from updated answer;

Comment: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method getColor(Landroid/content/Context;I)I in class Landroid/support/v4/content/ContextCompat; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat' appears in /data/app/com.test.app-1/base.apk)
            at com.afollestad.materialdialogs.MaterialDialog$Builder.<init>(MaterialDialog.java:478)
            at com.test.app.FragmentOption.onAttach(FragmentOption.java:32)

Comment: In my app,i'm using a ViewPager with a PagerTabStrip,if use 23.0.1 the PagerTabStrip not display the title,at first...! [link](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=183127)

Comment: @Johnny I'm sure that you can replace `PagerTabStrip` by `android.support.design.widget.TabLayout` from design lib that has no bugs)

Comment: Hey @mohax now the onAttach method is deprecated how can i do this in fragment i tried using context but it still showing error.

Comment: @SAVVY, see update answer (`UPD_1`). Or you mean, that you try `onAttach(Context context)` with no success?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45969328/how-to-use-the-filedialog-of-afollestad-material-dialogs

Comment: onAttach doesn't work because the view isn't created yet, you can use all the methods called after the view is created and the context is initialized. I think that the "onViewCreated" method will work (never tryed yet, if you look my answer below I explain why), also the "onStart" method will works too.

Answer (score 1):

You can't show in the "onCreateView" of the fragment because the view isn't created yet. Doing it in the "onAttach" method doesn't work too because the view isn't created. I suggest you to look fragment's lifecycle for more details. The "onAttach" method get called before the "onCreateView" when the fragment is attached to the activity.
Inside the "onAttach(Context context)" you can init your fragment's callbacks.

To show the dialog you can do it inside the "onStart" method or in every lifecycle method called after the view is created, the fragment is attached to the activity and the context is set. I think that the "onViewCreated" method will works too.

Personally I prefer to use DialogFragment instead of MaterialDialog; I normally use MaterialDialog only for prompt messages (so like an AlertDialog). For others things like confirm dialog, lists dialog, filters dialog, I prefer to build a dialog class extending DialogFragment because in that way I can easily re-use that base-dialog.
Also I normally implements all the "dialog logic" inside the activity, I put it inside fragment only if the fragment can do all is job alone without activity interaction (so, for example, if my fragment contains all the functionality I need instead of the visualization part alone).

I think that MaterialDialog is the fast way to show a dialog because you can instantiate it and show it just by using the builder method, so you don't have to worry about all the logic to show and manage the DialogFragment using the FragmentManager. 
Anyway the "fast way" isn't always the "better way" to do something.

Hope this is helpful, bye have a nice coding (: