# how to use the filedialog of afollestad/material-dialogs

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-context, android-library

I am trying to call this dialog in my fragment, I visited some thread regarding this and I came to know about the overriding the OnAtach method but this method is deprecated and I can no longer use that method

```
 @override
 public void onAttach(Context context) {
 super.onAttach(context);

context1=this.getActivity();
}
```

this is how I use to call the method but still, it is showing error red line in the builder method of the dialog this is the[library that I am using](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs)
I asked them  [here](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs/issues/1448) but no answer yet

```
  new FileChooserDialog.Builder(MainActivity.class)
                    .initialPath("/sdcard")
                    .mimeType("audio/*")
                    .tag("optional-identifier")
                    .goUpLabel("Back")
                    .show();
```

this is how i am calling

Comment: Try using (YourActivityName) getActivity(). ie.

(MainActivity) getActivity()

Comment: tried but its not  working

Comment: In your Activity, you need to implement FileChooserDialog.FileCallback

Comment: but the error is still there i implemented  this in my fragment also

Comment: What is the error, and also attach your code.

Comment: the build method can only take activity object thats the error

Comment: You need to cast it in your fragment

((MainActivity) getActivity())

Comment: thx it is working